# linux, how to redirect stdout from parent, but keep stdout into screen from children

Tags: linux

For example if we have two bash file.:

1) Master.bsh:

```
echo "I am master"
./Child.bsh
```

2) Child.bsh:

```
echo "I am child"
```

If we run ./Master.bsh, we receive both 2 message on the screen.
If we run ./Master.bsh > stdout.txt, we receive 0 message on the screen, both go to stdout.txt

Question: 
If we have any way after we run ./Master.bsh xxx???xxx??? stdout.txt, We can see "I am child" on the screen, but "I am master" in the stdout.txt

I cannot use below answer:

```
*Master: 
echo "I am master" > stdout.txt
./Child.bsh*
```

The only thing we can change is the command line. ./Master.bsh xxx???xxx??? stdout.xt